# VB.NET form should inherit C# project form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, forms

I would like my VB.NET form to inherit from a form defined in a C# project like so:

[image]

The code behind the C# form is rather complex, and I would really like to avoid re-writing it in VB.NET.

I was wondering if this should theoretically work and if I just made a mistake, or if this is not possible the way I planned it.

Thank you.

Comment: does the c# project compile when you build it alone?

Comment: and what errors you get?

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I got it.

I can reference the System.Windows.Forms.Ribbon dll in my project.
I don't need to include the C# project at all. :-)